# How to get info out of URL (or is it even a bad thing?)

Tags: php, url

So I'm kind of new to producing PHP applications in a highly secure environment (hospital website) and I am trying to be extra vigilant. There is a form on one of my pages where if an email address is invalid or if the form is left empty it redirects the user like this:

```
header("Location: /root/page.php?message=message to the person who messed up");
exit;
```

And the message is received on the page like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['message'])){
    echo "$_GET[message]";
}
```

So obviously the message is displayed in the URL. My question is two-fold:

1. Is that an unsafe thing to do?
2. If yes, I do I display the message to the user without having it in the URL?

Comment: Send a post request with AJAX

Comment: Directly echoing any user input without sanitation regardless of if it's in the url or a post request is unsafe.

Comment: There really is no need to redirect to a dedicated error page. Re-show the form with the error at the top of the page if you must.

Comment: @NoahCristino That's probably the best idea

Comment: @jfadich That's not user input I'm echoing, that's a short message I created.

Comment: @AdamMcGurk That is user input because anyone can take that URL and change the message to whatever they want then submit it. They could do the same thing with a post request. Never trust data from inside `$_POST` or `$_GET`

Comment: @Scuzzy That's what this is doing, re displaying the form. The form and the scripts page are two different pages. And this is the way I am showing the error at the top

Comment: @jfadich So what would be the best thing to do to display the error message?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, but one way would be to set the message to the session, then display the message if one exists in the session.

Comment: @jfadich OK I'll try that! And that's secure? Sorry for asking so many questions!

Comment: Also if security is such a huge concern writing this all yourself is not a good idea. It would be better to use a battle tested framework that does a lot of this for you.

Comment: @AdamMcGurk That would be more secure than what you have here

Comment: Well instead of sending the entire message you can send a number say 1 or 2 or 0 and then display message accordingly to the end user, just like we have error codes. But make sure you escape your $_GET variables before using them on the redirected page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use echo $_GET['message'] urs is missing single quotes inside the GET[''] part and u r using $_GET inside quotes. It should be done like " text".$_GET[] where the dot on the left of GET[] is concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I did to prevent the info being sent in the URL:
My "controller":

```
start_session();
...
$message = "Some message here";
$_SESSION['message'] = $message;
header("Location: /path/to/location");
```

The "view":

```
if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
    start_session();
    echo "$_SESSION['message'];
}
```